# Question with Copulas

Tags: self-study, copula, mathematical-statistics

I've come across this question in my class which I'm struggling with.

If we have the copula $C(u_1,u_2)=\phi^{-1}(\phi(u_1)+\phi(u_2))$ where $\phi(u) = (-\ln (u))^{\gamma}$ for ${\gamma} \ge 1$, express $C(u_1,u_2)$ as explicitly as possible.

Comment: Note that to get (e.g.) $\phi$ you just need a prior backslash e.g. \phi.

Comment: Self-study questions come with an obligation to show precisely what you have tried so far.

Comment: Try looking up the 'Gumbel-Hougaard' copula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The copula that you are looking for is the Gumbel-Hougaard copula.

First find $\phi^{-1}(u) = \exp(-u^{1/γ})$.

Then use this to express $C(u_1, u_2)$ explicitly:

\begin{align}
C(u_1, u_2) &= \phi^{-1}(\phi(u_1) + \phi(u_2))  \\
            &= \exp(-[\phi(u_1) + \phi(u_2)]^{1/γ})  \\
            &= \exp(-[(-\ln(u_1))^γ + (-\ln(u_2))^γ]^{1/γ})
\end{align}

This is the Gumbel-Hougaard copula which appeared in:

- Gumbel, E.J. (1960): "Bivariate exponential distributions." *Journal of the American Statistical Association* 55, 698–707.

A derivation of it can be found in:

- Hougaard, P.(1986): "A class of multivariate failure time distributions." *Biometrika* 73, 671–678.

Comment: Thank you for updating this. I took the liberty of formatting your answer using the $\LaTeX$ markdown the site supports. Please ensure it still says what you want it to.

Comment: Hi Jordan, welcome to CrossValidated. This is quite a good answer (so +1 for your effort), but I think for future questions like this it would be useful to take a read through the guidelines in the `self-study` [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info), in particular the section 'Answering self-study questions'.

Comment: Thanks - my original post (a hint to a self-studier) was relegated to a comment so I was under the impression that a full answer was more appropriate. Tricky business.